# Are there any downsides calling a function in javascript every ~100ms?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, setinterval

So I started exercising javascript and html for a couple of days now and I wanted to know if there are any downsides (especially looking at performance reasons) if I call a function every 80ms (with the **setInterval()** function).

I made a calculator and I have a function which "synchronizes" my input value with a label, which will also show me the result.

```
<label id="rechnung" for="eingabe"> </label>
<input id="eingabe" name="Eingabe" class="inputField" oninput="filterInput()">

 window.onload = setInterval(syncEingabeRechnung,80);
 function syncEingabeRechnung(){
      document.getElementById('rechnung').textContent = document.getElementById('eingabe').value;
 }
```

The reason with the repetitive calling is for cases when someone highlights characters and deletes them. This way the input field and the label wouldnt have identical values.

P.S.: If there is a better way to achieve my intend, then I would like to hear your ideas!

Comment: show us an sample What you have tried

Comment: There is quite a choice of events you can listen to (in a direct or delegated way) in order to find the right time for your synchronization action to happen. Very likely this would be a better approach than blindly calling you script into action more than ten times a second. Share some more of your actual html and your intentions and we can become more concrete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the performance cost would be very low (if your function just does what it says), besides the fact that that's a very bad approach. You would think that the browser knows *when* the user is typing, and maybe the browser thinks that it's a good idea to let the JS know as well. The browser has pre-provided built-in things for you to use that are much better, where you listen for any changes in input and update the label accordingly.

Something like this:

```js
const input = document.getElementById("inp"),
  l = document.getElementById("l");

// we can simply wait for the input event
input.addEventListener("input", () => {
  l.innerText = input.value; // update the label accordingly
});
```

```html
<label id="l" for="inp"></label>
<input placeholder="Type something..." id="inp" />
```

However you change the input contents (typing, highlighting, deleting), the change will always register.

Comment: Okay I see. In fact I tried it almost the exact same way before, but I used "keydown" event instead of "input". With "keydown" there was some kind of delay. It was always one character too slow. So if I typed in "12" the label would only show "1". But that doesnt seem to be the case with "input". So I will use that instead, thank you very much!

Comment: @Logiaa `keydown` fires once the user "presses the key down", and you won't be able to access the last typed character(s). If this was the answer to your question, could you accept it as correct? Thank you.